# error en codigo de ejercicio bucle for con string, javascript

Tags: javascript, bucle-for

tengo un ejercicio donde tengo que concatenar un string, y repetirlo 5 veces desde 0,pero cuando lo quiero ejecutar me tira error, y no logro encontrarlo

```
function pasandoPorI(){
    for (i=0; i <=5 ; i++){
        console.log (pasandoPorI("acá i tiene el valor de ..." + i))
    }
}
```

Comment: Tienes un límite excedido por que por dentro del ciclo estás volviendo a invocar a la función y eso llamaría al ciclo for de nuevo, basta que esta línea: `console.log (pasandoPorI("acá i tiene el valor de ..." + i))` quede así: `console.log ("acá i tiene el valor de ..." + i)`. Pues no tiene caso invocar a la función de nuevo cuando tu única intención es que el console imprima el texto y le concatene el valor que le iterador i va teniendo por cada vuelta

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que hay en el código es que se mete en un bucle infinito. 
Al entrar en el bucle vuelve a llamar a función (que tiene otro bucle) y así sucesivamente. Así bucle se crean infinitos bucles.

La solución es No llamar a la función en el bucle.

```
function pasandoPorI(){
    for (i=0; i <=5 ; i++){
        console.log ("acá i tiene el valor de ..." + i)
    }
}
```

Por el contrario si estás intentando hacer una función recursiva. Tendría que tener la siguiente forma.

```
i=0;
pasandoPorI(i);

function pasandoPorI(i){
        console.log ("acá i tiene el valor de ..." + i);
        i++;
        if (i>5){
            return "";
        }
        pasandoPorI(i);
}
```

Recuerda que una propiedad de las funciones recursivas es que deben tener condiciones de salida, para que no se quede dentro de un bucle infinito.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: y como puedo realizar para que ese bucle inicie en 0 y termine en 4?

Comment: Tienes 2 opciones. for (i=0; i <=4 ; i++) y for (i=0; i <5 ; i++)
Ten en cuenta que en la condición que tienes estas incluyendo al 5 al ponerle >= . En el ejemplo recursivo, la condición que busca es la contraria  if (i>=5) o  if (i>4) te valdrían